# Autolayout max width so text doesn't flow outside of screen/view

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a `UILabel` that is set to `Align Center X to Superview` and `Align Center Y to Superview`. It has no width so that it can changed based on the amount of text. A small icon also needs to sit to the left of the text:

[image]
[image]

[image]

The problem is, when too much text is added, it flows outside of the screen:

[image]

Even though there is a `UIView` that is a parent, which has leading and trailing space of 12, it still doesn't respect that parent view. The `UILabel` should be making the text size smaller to fit all the text, but it isn't doing this.

**How can I have a centered `UILabel` like this but still make it have a max width so that it will not flow outside of the screen?**

Comment: In IB I have Autoshrink set the Minimum Font size of 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UILabel won't be constrained by the parent view unless you specifically establish what those constraints should be. So by default it doesn't take the leading and trailing edges of the superview into account at all.

I would suggest adding a width constraint from the UILabel to its parent view that is of type "Less Than Or Equal" and has a constant of 0 and a multiplier of 0.85 or some other reasonable value.  This will let the label become very small or even zero width, but won't let it get larger than 85% of the width of its parent view.

Comment: I have never manually added a less than or equal constraint. How do I add that? Cntrl drag from label to parent doesn't give that option.

Comment: @Nic After you ctrl-drag and add the constraint, select the UILabel in the storyboard and open the right inspector panel for layout (this is the one with the little ruler icon).  You should see the width constraint listed there.  Click the "edit" button next to it, and in the popover, the top left dropdown lets you select either "=" "<=" or ">="

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the number of lines, minimum font size and `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`.

```
myLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
myLabel.minimumFontSize = 6;
myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

If there's still too much text, you either need to go multiline, clip the text, or use an ellipsis.

For multiline, set `myLabel.numberOfLines = 0`

To clip the text, set `myLabel.clipsToBounds = YES`

To truncate with an ellipsis, set `myLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail`

Comment: In IB I have Autoshrink set the Minimum Font size of 8. I assume that is the same as `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth`?

Comment: Yes, that's the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't seem to help anything. Text still goes outside of the screen.

Comment: If this has no effect and the text is not shrinking at all, then the label itself is probably resizing itself extremely wide, and you probably have a constraint problem.  Daniel Hall's answer pertains to the constraints.